# Запись в Couchdb - Python Django

Tags: python, django, couchdb

Всем привет,
Изучаю django и бд couchdb

При нажатии на галочку checkbox

*forms.py*

```
class myform(forms.Form):  
     opds=forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

нужно сделать запись в БД couchdb, если галочку снять запись удалить. Подскажите как это можно реализовать.

Если можно по подробнее

Comment: Навесить событие onChange на каждый checkbox. При удалении галочки отправлять DELETE на сервер, аналогично при нажатии.